# What happen to tag votes when you reach the dailly rep cap?

Tags: support

I was wondering if tag votes were also blocked when you are above the daily rep cap.

If users continue to vote for your questions/answers, does the system continue to increment the votes you're getting for a given tag?

I didn't pay attention to that count till I got my first bronze badge :)

(it was for [command-line](https://askubuntu.com/help/badges/70/command-line) IIRC).

Comment: I assume it does - as votes continue to increase, you just don't get the rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does. I got two tag badges today, with some votes not counting to rep from yesterday. :( Such votes also counts towards any score-based badges, like "Nice Answer", "Enlightened", etc.